# Get distinct strings from a list then create a new object and add it to the same list

Tags: c#

I am trying to find the distinct names of a `List<Person>` based on the `Name` property. For each distinct name, I want to create a new object with same name property and all other properties are null. How do I do it efficiently?

Person Class.

```cs
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

Program.cs

```cs
List<Person> personList = new List<Person>();

var p1 = new Person()
{
    Name = "John",
    Country = "USA"
};

var p2 = new Person()
{
    Name = "John",
    Country = "China"
};

var p3 = new Person()
{
    Name = "Bob",
    Country = "Italy"
};

var p4 = new Person()
{
    Name = "Bob",
    Country = "Brazil"
};

var p5 = new Person()
{
    Name = "Bob",
    Country = "Canada"
};

personList.Add(p1);
personList.Add(p2);
personList.Add(p3);
personList.Add(p4);
personList.Add(p5);
```

The aim is to add one more "John" and one more "Bob" to the same list (because they have distinct names) with country properties as the null string.

Comment: `personList.GroupBy(x => x.Name).Select(x => new Person{ Name = x.Key }).ToArray()`

Comment: @MetroSmurf Doesn't work !

Comment: Sure it does: https://dotnetfiddle.net/YY7kSS

Comment: @MetroSmurf aim is to add new two objects to the same list, so the total number of persons will become 7

Comment: Added an answer with the option of adding the distinct values to the existing list.

Comment: see the edit to my answer. You cannot simply call `.Distinct(x => x.Name)`. You should also read up on Linq expressions; I've included a link to the `Distinct` method in my edit. (and now you deleted your comment, so this comment looks dumb; but leaving it here for your reference)

Comment: @MetroSmurf I used your solution. It works fine. But an issue is, if i change any property (of an object) inside the new unique list, It will affect the original list as well ( pass by ref?). How could I avoid it.

Comment: Please open a new question since it's a complete different question. However, search SO for an answer first as it's been asked and answered multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a Linq query will make fairly easy work of finding all the distinct `Name` values:

```
// first use .GroupBy to group everything by the Name property
// and then select a new Person for each grouping of Name

Person[] unique = personList.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
    .Select(x => new Person{Name = x.Key})
    .ToArray();
```

Once the new collection is created; add them to the existing collection:

```
personList.AddRange(unique);
```

### Edit for use with `.Disinct`

Alternatively, you can get the distinct name values from the Linq `.Distinct()` method, instead of using the `.GroupBy()` method, but you need to select the `.Name` property to get an OOB distinct comparer:

```
Person[] unique = personList.Select(x => x.Name)
    .Distinct()
    .Select(x => new Person{Name = x})
    .ToArray();

personList.AddRange(unique);
```

Using the [Distinct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=net-5.0) requires either using a built in `IEqualityComparer`, or providing a custom `IEqualityComparer` in the overload. Simply passing in the object itself is not valid, unless the object implements `IEqualityComparer`. In this case, it's easier to either select the `Name` property and call `.Distinct` which will use the built-in `IEqualityComparer`, or use the `.GroupBy` method as in the first example.

Answer (score 0):

Use linq's Distinct method (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=net-5.0):

```
public class Person
        {
            
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Country { get; set; }
    
        }
    
    // Program.cs
    
    List<Person> personList = new List<Person> ();
    
                var p1 = new Person ()
                {
                    Name = "John",
                    Country = "USA"
                };
    
    
                var p2 = new Person ()
                {
                    Name = "John",
                    Country = "China"
                };
    
                var p3 = new Person ()
                {
                    Name = "Bob",
                    Country = "Italy"
                };
    
                var p4 = new Person ()
                {
                    Name = "Bob",
                    Country = "Brazil"
                };
    
                var p5 = new Person ()
                {
                    Name = "Bob",
                    Country = "Canada"
                };
    
    
                personList.Add(p1);
                personList.Add (p2);
                personList.Add (p3);
                personList.Add (p4);
                personList.Add (p5);
    
       
    
        var personsWithDistinctNameInPersonList = personList.Select(p => p.Name).Distinct()
              .Select(n => new Person {
                Name = n,
              }).ToList();
           personList.AddRange(personsWithDistinctNameInPersonList);
```

Comment: This fails both in the Distinct method (there is nothing defined as the comparer) and then will fail with an InvalidOperationException while trying to modify the collection during enumeration.

Comment: Since I am first selecting only the name property of every person, linq should be able to use the default build in string comparer just fine. In the piece of code provided there is no enumeration happening on the personList when the AddRange method is called.

Comment: I didn't see the `.Select` before. So that works, but the InvalidOperationEx will still occur because you need to materialize the query; as written it has yet to be materialized until you try to add it into the same collection.

Comment: `personsWithDistinctNameInPersonList` _is not_ evaluated until an operation such as `.ToArray()` or `.AddRange()` is called. This is called deferred evaluation. As currently written, it fails. Period. You need to invoke `.ToArray()` in order for your example to compile.

Comment: I added a ToList()